# MySQL LEFT JOIN with WHERE

Tags: mysql, left-join

Ive got two tables company and process. Company has field company_id and others. Process has fields company_id and status. I want all the fields of the company table only without those in the process table that have a status 0. Ive come sofar with the following but that gives me all the values of company even with the one of process table that has status 0.

```
SELECT  c.company_id
FROM    company c
LEFT JOIN 
   process p 
ON     c.company_id = p.company_id 
   AND p.status != '0'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT c.company_id 
FROM company c 
  LEFT JOIN process p 
    ON c.company_id = p.company_id 
WHERE p.status != '0'
  OR p.status IS NULL
;
```

2nd solution (edited and simplified):
This doesn't look like "hack", does it?

```
SELECT c.company_id 
FROM company c 
WHERE c.company_id NOT IN
  ( SELECT company_id
    FROM process
    WHERE status = '0'
  )
;
```

The problem with second solution is that if you want fields from table `process` to be shown, one more join will be needed (this query with `process`).

In the first solution, you can safely change first line to `SELECT c.company_id, c.company_title, p.status` or , `SELECT c.*, p.*`.

Comment: I tried it, works. Ill let you know if thats the final way. thanks

Comment: I guess this is the solution but this is rather a hack :-) not an exact solution because the null checks wether a record is there or not but does not check the status field value.

Comment: It's not a hack. It's more or less standard on how `LEFT JOIN` works (putting `NULL`s where no value can be put).

Answer (score 2):

First, your code is performing a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN, second you have no WHERE clause (it seems you are saying AND instead of WHERE).